# SQL check length of a list argument

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a following query in an Azure SQL database:

```
Select * 
from item_table 
where itemNumber IN (:itemNbr) or (:itemNbr) is null;
```

Means, if the passed list `:itemNbr` is null or empty then I want all the rows from the table.

The problem I am getting with this query is it runs fine if the `:itemNbr` is null or empty, but if I pass some objects in the list, then it becomes like this:

```
Select * 
from item_table 
where itemNumber IN ('2134234', '23423423') or ('2134234', '23423423') is null;
```

and I get this error while executing it:

> SQL Error [4145] [S0001]: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

I have tried `ISNULL`, `NULLIF` and some other ways but nothing is working correctly

Comment: So if :ItemNBr parameter is null, then you want no filters, else have filter. You should handle this condition in the application logic, not in sql. Add the where clause only if there is something to filter on.

Comment: @Shadow oh ok, so there is no way i can write a generic query which can handle this logic?

Answer (score 0):

Found one way to handle the same in the query itself, without changing the application code:

```
Select * from item_table where (COALESCE(:itemNbr,1) = 1 or  itemNumber in ( :itemNbr ));
```

So Now, if we pass the arg `itemNbr` as null then it will fetch all the rows from the table or else it will filter the rows basis on the `itemNbr` argument.